# i want to pass a value in some part of string in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

can we use string formatting in dictionary somehow. this is my code requirement-
in the place of curly braces I want to use any value like which is stored in variable invoice id.how to pass that value in a dict.

```
    INVOICE_NOT_EXIST = {'invoice': 'object with id={} does not exist.'}
    
    invoice_id = 5214
    
    detail={INVOICE_NOT_EXIST}
#   detail={INVOICE_NOT_EXIST}.format(invoice_id)   # this is an error as we know 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'
```

if I do like this then it is set but my requirement is dictionary.

```
INVOICE_NOT_EXIST = "'invoice': 'object with id={} does not exist.'"

invoice_id = 5214

detail={INVOICE_NOT_EXIST.format(invoice_id)}
```

is there a way......which can meet my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```py
INVOICE_NOT_EXIST = {'invoice': 'object with id={} does not exist.'}
invoice_id = 5214
detail = INVOICE_NOT_EXIST['invoice'].replace("{}", invoice_id)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(detail)
object with id=5214 does not exist.
```

However, I think you should change the way you handle these errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think that I should handle this like that and I am not handling errors like this, I just posted a similar question that matches my requirements.